# Jquery cant get dynamic data

Tags: jquery, dynamic-programming

I am a noob to using jQuery. I have a problem with an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

I am using version 1.9.0 of jQuery. I am creating a dynamic number of record, each record would create a `tr` in a table, also I want to add some dynamic coding into the textbox

Part of my Html markup:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="row_1">
        <td class="value">
            <input id="1" name="collections[appearance][headersubcolor][entity_id1][name]" value="0" class="Root Catalog input-text" type="text">
            <p class="note">
                <span>Click inside to change a color of each Category</span>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="scope-label">
        </td>
        <td class="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_2">
         <td class="label">
             <td class="value">
                  <input id="2" name="collections[appearance][headersubcolor][entity_id2][name]" value="0" class="Default Category input-text" type="text">....
```

jQuery code:

```
 $('tr[id^="row_"]'.each(function(){
     var rowid = parsInt(this.id.replace("row_",""));
     console.lof("id:"+ rowid);
            var ??? = new jscolor.color(document.getElementById('???'), {})
 });
```

$('tr[id^="row_"]'.each(function()  <--- i cant getting the DATA

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but immediately I see a few syntax errors ... missing closing tag on the selector, should be $('tr[id^="row_"]').each( ... and console.lof instead of console.log , var ??? is invalid too (or are you asking us what you should name your variables?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error #2 : (bracket is missing before .each starts)

```
$('tr[id^="row_"]'.each(function(){
     var rowid = parsInt(this.id.replace("row_",""));
     console.lof("id:"+ rowid);
            var ??? = new jscolor.color(document.getElementById('???'), {})
 });
```

it should be

```
$('tr[id^="row_"]').each(function(){
     var rowid = parseInt(this.id.replace("row_",""));
     console.log("id:"+ rowid);
            var ??? = new jscolor.color(document.getElementById('???'), {})
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Error #1:**

```
var rowid = parsInt(this.id.replace("row_",""));
```

It should be [`parseInt(string, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) like :-

```
var rowid = parseInt(this.id.replace("row_",""), 10);
             ___^___
```

**Error #2:**

```
console.lof("id:"+ rowid);
```

It should be :-

```
console.log("id:"+ rowid);
       ___^___
```

**Error #3:**

```
 $('tr[id^="row_"]'.each(function(){
```

It should be :-

```
 $('tr[id^="row_"]').each(function(){
                ___^___
```

Comment: He is also missing the closing parenthesis before `.each`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistypes there,

```
parseInt and console.log
//$('tr[id^="row_"]' - needs a ) 
//like this: 
$('tr[id^="row_"]');
```

//run the following in your console:

```
$('tr[id^="row_"]');
```

If it doesent return elements, your selector (css) is wrong.